# Mathematical expression for self-inductance constant $L$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, calculus, inductance

Is there a mathematical expression for what the value of $L$ (self-inductance constant) is for a given geometry? I've tried to come up with something, but I don't know if it's right or not...

$$\phi_B=\int \int_S \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dA}$$ (Definition of Flux)

$$\vec{B}=\int \frac{\mu_0 I}{4 \pi} \frac{\vec{dl} \times \hat{r}}{||\vec{r}||^2}$$ (Biot-Savart Law)

$$\phi_B=\int \int_S \ \int \frac{\mu_0 I(t)}{4 \pi} \frac{\vec{dl} \times \hat{r}}{||\vec{r}||^2} \cdot \vec{dA}$$ (Combining previous statements)

$$\epsilon_i=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi_B$$
$$\epsilon_i=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int \int_S \ \int \frac{\mu_0 I(t)}{4 \pi} \frac{\vec{dl} \times \hat{r}}{||\vec{r}||^2} \cdot \vec{dA}$$
$$\epsilon_i=-\frac{\partial I(t)}{\partial t} \int \int_S \ \int \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \frac{\vec{dl} \times \hat{r}}{||\vec{r}||^2} \cdot \vec{dA}$$
Using $\epsilon_i=-L\frac{\partial I(t)}{\partial t}$, can we therefore infer that:
$$L\equiv \int \int_S \ \int \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \frac{\vec{dl} \times \hat{r}}{||\vec{r}||^2} \cdot \vec{dA}$$ for a given geometry?

Comment: You know what they say about "old fiddles" well is the equivalent, a [1916 publication by the Bureau of Standards](http://hamwaves.com/inductance/doc/rosa.1916.3ed.pdf) (now NIST), a [more recent one](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/69c/jresv69cn2p127_a1b.pdf) and there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

Self inductance is purely magnetostatic property. No need for Faraday’s law. The issue with your approach is that you’ll formally get infinite inductance. Tou can already see the beginning of the problem in your formula since the integrand diverges on the loop. A 1D loop of current has infinite inductance. You’ll therefore need to regularize your integral by assuming that the loop has a certain width.

In general, the usual approach is, given the current distribution $j$, to calculate the magnetic field $B$ (using Biot-Savart in general or Ampère with symmetries) and deduce the energy:
$$
E=\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\int B^2d^3x
$$
Using:
$$
E=L\frac{I^2}{2}
$$
you then identify the self-inductance.

Look at the [formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor#Inductance_formulas) for the most common self-inductance. At leading order, the width of the loop dominates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helped a lot, but I don't quite understand what you mean by getting an infinite inductance. I tried it out on an example with just a simple solenoid of radius "a" producing an internal field in the $\hat{k}$ direction, and it seemed to work:
$$\int \int_S \ \int \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{\vec{dl} \times \hat{r}}{||\vec{r}||^2} \cdot \vec{dA}$$
Knowing that for a solenoid, $\vec{B} = \mu_0 I(t) n \hat{k}$:
$$\int \int_S \mu_0 n \hat{k} \cdot \hat{k}dA$$
$$\int \int \mu_0 n dA$$
$$L \equiv \mu_0 n \pi a^2$$
Which is correct for a solenoid...

Comment: also may I ask where you got the formula $E=\frac{1}{2\mu_0} \int B^2 d^3x$? Is this the same as saying $E=\frac{1}{2\mu_0} \int \int \int B^2 dV$? I understand that this would mean we're integrating over some energy density, $\frac{B^2}{2\mu_0}$, but where does this formula for energy density come from? I've seen it before, but only in the very specific context of inductors and RLC circuits

Comment: For your first comment, the infinite solenoid is a 2D sheet of current so my objection does not apply. The subtlety in this was is appropriately defining the surface for the magnetic flux. In the case of the solenoid, due to invariance by translation, there is one obvious candidate, but in general it is less obvious. Consider for example the boundary currents of a uniformly magnetised ball for example.

Comment: Yes, $d^3x$ is just another notation for $dV$. The formula for magnetic energy is very general. It's the energy required for creating the magnetic field. Even if the magnetic force does not work, varying magnetic fields induce electric fields, so you still need to provide work to create a magnetic field from currents. The formula is proved in this general context in standard EM textbooks like Griffiths' or Jackson's.